# Cakephp Optimizing JSON Response

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I am really new to how to optimize and I am utilizing Cake PHP, Authenticate and a function that returns results for the user that calls the function. I am wanting to optimize the speed of the JSON Response, because right now it is taking 70,000 ms to call 2 rows from the database.

When I call the function in the browser it loads very fast, but its not JSON Formated. Using POSTMAN I set the following parameters in the header:

`'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json'`

When doing so it takes about 70,000ms to retrieve 2 lines from the database.

The Function that queries the database:

```
 public function recent()
    {
        $supplementEntry = $this->SupplementEntry->find('all')
            ->contain(['Supplement'])
            ->order(['Date_Entered' => 'DESC'])
            ->limit(5);

        $this->set(compact('supplementEntry'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['supplementEntry']);
    }
```

Where should I start to investigate in CakePHP to make the response < 1000ms?

Is there logging I can enable to see where the bottle neck is occuring (ie. Query, Authentication Check, converting to json)?

Comment: Use the timer tab from DebugKit to see what part takes how much time and query times and use Xdebugs profiler for getting a detailed profile for your calls and to see how often something is called and how much time it takes.

Comment: Try it with debug disabled.

Comment: Awesome thank you both!!! Turning off Debug mode really made it go quicker and I learned something new about DebugKit. Thanks!